# Can you toggle finite blocks in Minecraft Creative Mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

By default, blocks in your hotbar are infinite, but it'd be nice to enable finite blocks for the purpose of being able to place `x` blocks by having `x` in your hotbar.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does switching to survival mode not work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "x" blocks. The blocks in your hotbar are not infinite. It's the Creative Mode making you place them infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `/fill X Y Z   X Y Z  Minecraft:[block you want to fill with]`  command for up to 32768 blocks at a time.
Simply point your cursor at the block you want to select and use the `tab` key to auto fill co-ordinates - 3x tab for full co-ordinates (X,Y,Z).
I use this all the time when building large scale, you might also find it useful. One advantage is that you don't need to have the block you want to fill with in your inventory.

Comment: 1600 is not the limit, it's 32768.

Comment: My bad, I haven't checked recently - not that it really matters, it only means you are restricted to filling a certain amount at a time. Also I think it's possible to bypass the restrictions anyway...

Comment: It has always been 32768. And no, you can't bypass that, you can only use the command multiple times.

Comment: I've been aware of work arounds for older versions of java edition as seen here: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+exceed+%2Ffill+block+limit+minecraft&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB813GB813&oq=how+to+exceed+%2Ffill+block+limit+minecraft&aqs=chrome..69i57.17879j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_fxOWXfy-FISd1fAPqpG-kAU22 I also know of mods which remove the limit without having to use other commands/ tools

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 happy now? >:/

Comment: @117Halo Actually, I'm the reason he wrote that. If it hadn't for me submitting an edit to fix it... well... yes, I am happy now.

Comment: @ahmettrPro don't worry about it. I've amended the good year and a half old post ... I'm sure people could have just read the comments but it's done now ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

If you just want this for a few specific types of blocks, you can create a scoreboard of type `used:<block_ID>` and then run the command `clear @p <block_ID> 1` (and reset the score) whenever this score is 1.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are unable to toggle finite blocks in Minecraft Creative Mode; however, despite being very difficult to set up, this is possible to implement with commands. I don't think anyone would really try to do it though.

Comment: That's disappointing! So, when building scale models, you're forced to count the number of blocks you place versus leaving it to a preset amount in your inventory?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you if you're open to running a server (but only playing locally), you can:

1. Start up a Bukkit/Spigot Server
2. Install Essentials (there's lots of variants out there, doesn't matter which one, as long as it works) and WorldEdit.
3. Run `//` (on a bare hand) to instantly break stuff (from WorldEdit)
4. Run `/fly` to let you fly in Survival (from Essentials)
5. Just `/give`, `/i`, etc. the items you need (from Vanilla and/or Essentials)

You can take damage (except fall), insta-break, fly but anything you need has to be spawned in using the `/give` command and stuff is finite.

This was pretty much the old form of Creative before Creative Mode was even a thing.